# ViewPager behaves in an unexpected way

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My goal is to implement a *Guide/How-To-Use-App Activity* in my app, where users can flip between a predefined set of views. So, I decided to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

This is how I did in my `GuideActivity`:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mAdapter = new GuideAdapter(getBaseContext());
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And this is my implementation of [`PagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html):

```
class GuideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;  
    protected static final int[] SLIDES = new int[] { 
        R.drawable.page1, R.drawable.page2, R.drawable.page3 };

    public GuideAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(container.getContext());
        image.setImageResource(SLIDES[position]);
        container.addView(image, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SLIDES.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the images is drawn in top of each other. If I scroll from left to right, I see no images. If I scroll back, images shown for a second then disappear. **Bottom Line:** my ViewPager behave in an unexpected way!

I overridden the *four required methods* in [`PagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html). I'm not sure what I did wrong but I think it has something to do with `instantiateItem()` and/or `destroyItem()`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: it looks you need to properly implement isViewFromObject().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#isViewFromObject(android.view.View, java.lang.Object)

Comment: That's it! just `return arg0 == arg1` solved it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

This is needed:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
{
return view == object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @beworker pointed out, I wasn't implementing [`isViewFromObject()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#isViewFromObject%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object%29) properly. I thought I was!

Here is how I fixed it:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == arg1;
}
```